# Easier and more maintainable ways to insert HTML elements from configuration file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm working on a toy project right now that is entirely reliant on javascript.  Part of the project relies on a json file for configuration and description of the types of inputs as well as range values and/or options.  This will allow me to drasically extend and modify the content while keeping static HTML requirements very low.

Part of the code requires iterating over the input descriptions and building the appropriate HTML elements, inserting them into the DOM and initializing with the appropriate UI widget.  I am currently using a string concatenation function to create a HTML-formatted string which is then added to the DOM via `S.append(value)`.

For a given config file with the format

```
var config = {

    "effects" : [
    {     
        "id" : "asdf_sort",
        "name" : "asdf",
        "function" : "sortPixels",
        "params" : [
            {
                "name" : "img",
                "type" : "Image"
            },
            {
                "name" : "mode",
                "type" : "number"
            },
            {
                "name" : "iterations",
                "type " : "number"
            }

        ],
        "originalImage" : "images/asdf_sort.jpg",
        "afterImage" : "images/asdf_sort_after.jpg",
        "mouseoverText" : "Javascript implementation of &lt;a href = &quot;https://github.com/kimasendorf/ASDFPixelSort&quot;&gt;Kim Asendorf&quot;s Pixel Sort algorithm&lt;/a&gt;",  

        "inputs" : {
            "sliders" : [
                {
                    "name" : "iterations",
                    "default" : 1,
                    "min" : 1,
                    "max" : 20,
                    "range" : true
                }
            ],
            "dropdowns" : [
                {
                    "name" : "mode",
                    "values" : [
                        {
                            "value" : 0,
                            "text" : "Black Sort"
                        },
                        {
                            "value" : 1,
                            "text" : "Brightness Sort"
                        },
                        {
                            "value" : 2,
                            "text" : "White Sort"
                        }
                    ]
                }   
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to build the input slider section, I wrote the function

```
//takes in the sliders array and creates and appends the HTML elements to the
//DOM, then initializes with the jQuery UI Slider widget
function buildSliders(sliders, name){

    var appendString = "";

    //build html string and add to dom
    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
        appendString += "<div class = 'slider_element'><div class = 'slider_label effect_label effect_input " + name +
            "_effect'>" + sliders[i].name.capitalize() + "</div><div id = '" + name + "_slider_" + 
            sliders[i].name + "' class = 'effect_slider " + name + "_effect effect_input'>" + 
            "</div><div class = 'slider_value effect_label "+ name + "_effect' id = '" + sliders[i].name + 
            "_value'></div></div>";
    }

    $("#image_controls").append(appendString);

    //initialize jQuery UI Slider widget for each slider element
    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++){
        $("#" + name + "_slider_" + sliders[i].name).slider({
            range : true,
            min : sliders[i].min,
            max : sliders[i].max,
            value : sliders[i].default,
            step : 1,
            slide : function(event, ui){
                var name = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[2];
                $("#" + name + "_value").text(ui.value);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Its working, but that `appendString +=` bit of the for loop is a maintenance and modification nightmare.  However, I really can't think of an easier and more maintainable way to implement this.

One alternative is to mimic C's `sprintf` function and use `%d`, `%s` and other placeholders for variables to build the string.  However, this still requires me to create the HTML string in the first place.

What are some alternatives that I can use?

Comment: Pretty much any templating library - I'd start with Mustache.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @A.Wolff, I have to disagree.  Many questions are on here asking how to improve code snippets which are otherwise working but have drastic issues.

Comment: @Jason This is your opinion, i respect it. Hope you'll get an answer which will fit your needs

Comment: I think it's easier to maintain stuff like this with a little more order, something like this (quickly written and untested) -> http://jsfiddle.net/mgVFY/

Comment: @Jason, take a look at using createDocumentFragment(): [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup should be stored separately (ideally in a different document that you can load via ajax) but you can also just store in a variable. Like

```
markup = "<div class = 'slider_element'>...</div>"
```

Then you can just assign this string (as a jquery object) to a local variable

```
var slide_elem = $(markup);
```

Then, using the [$() context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1), you can manipulate this object as if it was a DOM object

```
$('.slider_label', slide_elem).addClass(name+'_effect').append(sliders[i].name);
$('.effect_slider', slide_elem).attr('id', name+'_slider_'+sliders[i].name).addClass(name+'_effect');
$('.slider_value', slide_elem).attr('id', sliders[i].name+'_value').addClass(name+'_effect');
```

And finally you can append it to your DOM

```
$(<your target element>).append(slide_elem);
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdmartin/q4X2u/)